# Move all zeroes in a given array to the end and replace each non-zero element with the closest greater value, if any

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, stack

Looking for the optimised solution for the below problem.

Given an unsorted array, we are required to move all zeroes to the end of the array and at same time find the next closest greater number of each element(non-zero) and return the same element incase if there is no next greater element for an element in the array .

> Input = {6,1,5,0,0,3,8,6,4}
> Output = {8,3,6,4,8,6,4,0,0}

I tried the below :

```
public class next_closest_element {

  public static void main(String[] arg) {
    int[] input = {6, 1, 5, 0, 0, 3, 8, 6, 4};
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    int k = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int last_index_value =input.length-1;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      if (input[i] != 0) {

        int j = i + 1;
        boolean flag = false;
        while (j < input.length && input[i] != 0) {

          if (input[j] > input[i]) {
            if (stack.empty() || !flag) {
              stack.push(input[j]);
              flag = true;
              j++;
            } else if (stack.peek() > input[j]) {
              stack.pop();
              stack.push(input[j]);
              flag = true;
              j++;
            } else {
              j++;
            }
          } else {
            j++;
          }
        }
        if (flag) {
          input[k] = stack.peek();
          k++;
        }
        else {
          input[k]=input[i];
          k++;
        }

      }
      else{
        count +=1;
      }
    }

    while(count>0){
      input[last_index_value]=0;
      last_index_value--;
      count--;
    }
    for (int s :
      input) {
      System.out.println(s);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: When you say next greater element, it should be there on the right side of the element or it could be anywhere?

Comment: Based on the example it looks like it should be on the right. If we ignore the zeroes in the original, we have `[6, 1, 5, 3, 8, 6, 4] -> [8, 3, 6, 4, 8, 6, 4]`.  For the `4` at index `6`, `5 > 4` but it seems that because the `5` was to the left of index `6`, it was ignored.

Comment: It's definitely possible to solve this in O(N * log(N)) time by building a balanced BST as we traverse from right to left, but my intuition tells me that using a monodeque to further reduce the runtime might be possible... however when drawing out the process, even with two deques I end up having to make O(N) inserts/removals in the worst case.

Comment: If the next greater has to be picked up from the right, you can use merge function of merge sort to accomplish this. This question is similar to count inversions, except for the fact that there we go for counts.

Comment: @nice_dev and wLui155 yes next greater element on the right side

Answer (score 0):

First shoveling the zeroes to the right would be one optimisation.

Possibly replacing with next closest greater element I have interpreted as next following element (as you seemed to do, as otherwise the last 4 might have become the overwritten 5).

```
static int[] f(int[] values) {
    // In-situ (in-place) algorithm.

    int n = 0; // The count of non-zero values.
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
        if (values[i] != 0) {
            values[n] = values[i];
            ++n;
        }
    }
    // Zero the rest:
    // (With a second array the remaining values from n upwards would
    // already be zero.)
    for (int i = n; i < values.length; ++i) {
        values[i] = 0;
    }

    // {6, 1, 5, 0, 0, 3, 8, 6, 4} -> {6, 1, 5, 3, 8, 6, 4, [n] 0, 0}
    // (First optimisation.) Now we only need to deal with n non-zero values.

    // Search the next (A) closest greatest (B) number, when found substitute.
    // Unoptimized:
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int ithValue = values[i];
        boolean hasClosest = false;
        int closest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
            int jthValue = values[j];
            if (jthValue > ithValue && (!hasClosest || jthValue < closest)) {
                closest = jthValue;
                hasClosest = true;
                values[i] = jthValue;
            }
        }
    }
    // {8, 3, 6, 4, 8, 6, 4, 0, 0}
    return values;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] input = {6, 1, 5, 0, 0, 3, 8, 6, 4};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(f(input)));
}
```

The last piece is not well optimized.

An other interpretation of "closest greatest:"

```
    int[] sorted = Arrays.copyOf(values, n);
    Arrays.sort(sorted);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int j = Arrays.binarySearch(sorted, values[i] + 1);
        if (j < 0) { // Not found 1 greater.
            j = ~j; // Even greater.
        }
        if (j < n) {
            values[i] = sorted[j];
        }
    }
    // {8, 3, 6, 4, 8, 8, 5, 0, 0}
```

Sorting cost O(N log N), as does the loop O(N) times binary search O(log N).
So it is faster, costing memory. But that is comparible with you stack usage.

By the way, a cleaned up version of your code could have been put on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).